# Excel Data validation won't sort based on column value

Tags: excel, validation, sorting, excel-formula

I have a simple absence schedule file, in sheet DATA column B there are some names of co-workers (or letters in this case..) in sheet JAN column C those names appear again (if a 1 is selected in sheet DATA column C) but that's not the point.

**Problem: those names have to be sorted sometimes (when new one's appear) but the DATA VALIDATION columns in sheet JAN don't sort with them (see colors in rows)
I don't want to use VBA because i don't know it, so hopefully there is a formula solution (use formula in the data validation popup? something with INDIRECT?)**

Hopefully someone can't help me out with this.

[TEST FILE](http://ufile.io/xyymh)

As in picture below, left side is the DATA SHEET where there are some names filled in, on the right side is the JAN SHEET where those names are displayed with an IF formula, when we sort the names in DATA SHEET they will sort in JAN SHEET as well, but the DATA VALIDATION in JAN SHEET from column D tot H isn't changing with it. I don't want to solve it with VBA because i don't know it, so thought to fix it with a formula, but can't find a solution.. read something that you can add a formula to the data validation list popup (INDIRECT...).

[image]

Comment: Instead of linking to a file, can you post some data here (or at least a screenshot)? It's unclear what you're trying to do - sort a table, but one of the columns isn't sorting with the other info?

Answer (score 0):

In the Jan sheet you are referencing the cells in the Data sheet with a formula and then you have formulas and enter values in the columns next to the cell reference. If the data in the Data sheet changes and gets re-ordered, the cells in Jan, column D will show the new sort order, but you need to understand that this does not affect all the data in the columns to the right. You only sorted the DATA sheet, but not the Jan sheet.

This is a flaw in the data architecture of the workbook. Don't use cell references to the data sheet for the names and for the formulas in D to J. The cells in columns D to J have formulas that refer to the DATA sheet, as well as data validation drop-downs. That is a dangerous thing to do. If the sort order of the DATA sheet changes, the cells that still use a formula will refer to the rows, but the cells where a value has been picked from the list may not match up with the correct name, as you have found out.

I suggest you copy and paste the names from DATA to Jan. Then use a formula that calculates the value based on a Vlookup with the Name as the lookup value.

If a new name gets added to the DATA sheet, you need to manually copy and paste that name to the Jan sheet.

Now you can sort the Jan sheet by column C. The formulas will show the correct value because they will look it up based on the name. The cells with a value picked from the data validation will travel with the sort if the whole range is selected before sorting.

Comment: Teylyn, yes i understand what your saying, but that's what i want to prevent in this case, i don't want to copy paste each time somebody new starts, then i have to copy paste this person each month manualy again.
That's why i tried to solve with only 1 sheet where all information is shown and the monts will do a lookup based on the 1 and 0 in DATA, this way i would only edit 1 sheet instead of 13..

Comment: Re-think your data architecture, because the referencing does not work. Or create a macro that when the sheet is selected, the names are automatically copied from the data column. That's not too hard to do. Referencing the DATA sheet does not work, so forget that approach.

Comment: I want to avoid macro's and vba, i have some sort of knowledge of excel but few of my collegues has none.. so wan't to keep it simple and dynamic. I keep wondering why we can't sort data validation rows that depend of a value from another column/row, in the data validation popup we can add formulas to our list source so.. maybe i'm thinking too much out of the box :)

Comment: Because what you do is not sorting. You are changing the sort order on the DATA sheet only. The cells on the Jan sheet that have formulas referring to the data sheet will adjust. But the cells where the formulas have been overwritten won't change because they have no connection to the original row of data anymore. Please understand that this approach does not work.